# how to show a text Statut in my wall facebook after it Posted

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-3.0

I have been searching a lot to find a way to do this. But nothing seems to be working for me. Can someone please help in doing this?
this is my code

`import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.android.DialogError;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook.DialogListener;
import com.facebook.android.FacebookError;
import com.facebook.android.Util;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  Facebook fb;
  SharedPreferences sp;
  ImageView pic,button;
  TextView welcome;
  Button post;
 private static final String[] PERMISSIONS = new String[] {
"user_about_me",
"user_activities",
"user_birthday",
"user_checkins",
"user_education_history",
"user_events",
"user_groups",
"user_hometown",
"user_interests",
"user_likes",
"user_location",
"user_notes",
"user_online_presence",
"user_photo_video_tags",
"user_photos",
"user_relationships",
"user_relationship_details",
"user_religion_politics",
"user_status",
"user_videos",
"user_website",
"user_work_history",
"email",

"read_friendlists",
"read_insights",
"read_mailbox",
"read_requests",
"read_stream",
"xmpp_login",
"ads_management",
"create_event",
"manage_friendlists",
"manage_notifications",
"offline_access",
"publish_checkins",
"publish_stream",
"rsvp_event",
"sms",
//"publish_actions",

"manage_pages"
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    post=(Button)findViewById(R.id.post);
    String APP_Id=getString(R.string.APP_ID);
    fb=new Facebook(APP_Id);
    sp=getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String acces_token=sp.getString("access_token", null);
    long expires=sp.getLong("access_expires",0);
    if(acces_token != null){
        fb.setAccessToken(acces_token);
    }
    if(expires != 0){
        fb.setAccessExpires(expires);
    }

    button=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.login);
    pic=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.picture_pic);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(fb.isSessionValid()){

            try {
                fb.logout(getApplicationContext());
                updateButtonImage();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }else{
fb.authorize(MainActivity.this,PERMISSIONS,fb.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH ,new DialogListener() {

                    @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "fbError", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(DialogError e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onError", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Editor editor=sp.edit();
            editor.putString("access_token", fb.getAccessToken());
            editor.putLong("access_expires", fb.getAccessExpires());
                        editor.commit();
                        updateButtonImage();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onCancel",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
    updateButtonImage();
}
private void updateButtonImage() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(fb.isSessionValid()){
        post.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
        button.setImageResource(R.drawable.logout);
        pic.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
        JSONObject obj=null;
        URL img_url=null;




        try {
            String jsonUser = fb.request("me");
            obj=Util.parseJson(jsonUser);
            String id=obj.optString("id");
            String name=obj.optString("name");
            welcome=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.welcome);
            welcome.setText("Welcome " + name);
    img_url=new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/"+id+"/picture?type=normal");
Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(img_url.openConnection().getInputStream());
            pic.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        } catch (FacebookError e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }else{
        post.setVisibility(Button.INVISIBLE);
        button.setImageResource(R.drawable.login_button);
        pic.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
public void buttonClicks(View v){
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.post:
        // Post
        fb.dialog(MainActivity.this, "feed", new DialogListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    fb.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
}`

Can someone point in the right direction? :)
    thanks for all

Comment: What is the exact problem you're facing?  Do you have incorrect output?  Error messages?  Any particular place in the code?

Comment: no everything's alright ... but I want showing the status in my timeline wall after it posted ... I mean a redirecting to my profil